# Quickest way to move whole folder's files to other folder using PHP

Tags: php, copy, rename, move

In php , rename function allow moving files to other folder
however, what is the most efficient way to move all files from one folder to another folder?

`@rename($fail_path, $incoming_path);` is not working

If I have to implement this, 
I need to

```
foreach (scandir($fail_path) as $file){
  rename($fail_path.$file, $incoming_path.$file);
}
```

Is it consume resource / are there more straight way? thanks

Comment: windows or linux run the appropriate command with exec()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function? Using shell_exec to call mv command.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```

Method I found from collegue.

> $src - source folder, $dst - target folder.

Comment: Old and obsolete method, unreliable also. @mkdir.. seriously?